# What is a minimal config to select for cygwin install?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, ubuntu, cygwin

What is a minimal config to select for cygwin install?

```
crond, not cron
sh runs
cat
tail
grep
emailing from shell
```

Only simple SHs

```
d:
cd D:\Программы\Tomcat\bin
catalina jpda start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cygwin Setup install be default only the packages in the base category plus the libraries needed by those packages.

[image]

Bash, Dash, cat, tail, grep are included in those packages.

crond is available from busybox.
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/busybox/busybox-1.23.2-1

From mail you can use `email`.